# "ele/ela ficou meio/meia desconfiada" x "ele/ela ficou todo/toda arrepiada"

Tags: gênero, concordância, advérbios

Aprendi nos meu tempos de estudante de escola primária que advérbios são invariáveis em gênero e número. E que qualquer palavra que se refira a um adjetivo é um advérbio. Nos exemplos abaixo, *"meio"* e *"todo"* referem-se a *desconfiado* e *arrepiado* respectivamente e são, portanto, advérbios.

- **"ele ficou meio desconfiado"**.   Como é que ele ficou?  resposta: meio desconfiado
- **"ele ficou todo arrepiado"** Como foi que ele ficou?  resposta: todo arrepiado.

Vejamos então o seguinte:

- **"ele ficou meio desconfiado"** - ao passarmos para o feminino temos que respeitar a regra de que advérbios são invariáveis em gênero, e temos então **"ela ficou meio desconfiada".** (ela ficou **meia desconfiada** é considerado errado)
- **"ele ficou todo arrepiado"** - ao passarmos para o feminino simplesmente ignoramos o fato que "todo" é um advérbio, e então temos **"ela ficou toda arrepiada"**.

Minha pergunta então: **porque podemos variar o gênero de alguns advérbios (todo, próximo) mas não o de outros (meio)**

Outros exemplos:

- "**ele** permaneceu **próximo** do local do acidente.
- "**elas** permaneceram **próximas** do local do acidente.

Nesse último exemplo "próximo" não se refere a um adjetivo, mas acrescenta uma condição de lugar ao verbo permanecer, sendo portanto um advérbio.

Comment: Uma hipótese: *meio* pode referir somente ao adjetivo, mas outros advérbios podem aludir, duma forma, ao sujeito. Quer dizer, *toda* pode aludir a "toda ela", e *próximas* que elas ficam "pessoas próximas", enquanto *meio* é entendido somente como *pouco* ou *muito*, que não refere nada ao sujeito. (Mesmo se *toda* é usado para significar *muito*, talvez o simples facto que pode significar "toda ela" bastou para fixar o costume.)

Answer (score 2):

O comentário do Dan Getz explica bem o fenômeno. Veja também que não faz sentido modificar um adjetivo com *todo*. Imagine tentar descrever o grau de desconfiança:

- *Um pouco* desconfiado
- *Meio* desconfiado
- *Muito* desconfiado
- *Totalmente* desconfiado

mas... *todo* desconfiado? Nesse caso, o modificador não se refere ao adjetivo em si, mas é um pronome que se refere a quem está desconfiado. *Ele todo* (ou *ela toda*) ficou desconfiado (ou desconfiada).

Já com o seu exemplo de *permanecer próximo*, é interessante notar que há duas interpretações possíveis: uma é tratar *próximo* como um adjetivo que descreve o sujeito, e portanto concorda com ele. É fácil visualizá-la quando comparamos com casos sem ambiguidade:

- Ele permaneceu interessado no tema.
- Ela permeneceu interessada no tema.

A outra interpretação é tratar *próximo a*/*próximo de* como uma locução prepositiva, e aí sim ela é inflexível:

- Ela permaneceu *próximo* do local do acidente.

Mas isso não invalida a possibilidade de usarmos *próximo* como um adjetivo que se refere ao sujeito, como você escreveu:

- Ela permeneceu *próxima* do local do acidente.

Comment: O exemplo que dei com "todo" não foi "desconfiado", mas sim "arrepiado".

Comment: Verdade, mas a ideia é a mesma.

Comment: Todo nao poderia ser um substituto de totalmente? "Arrepiado Em todo corpo" -> "arrepiado (No) todo" -> "todo arrepiado"

Comment: @BrunoCosta não exatamente. Totalmente é um advérbio, e não pode modificar um substantivo ou pronome. Portanto, sempre está caracterizando o adjetivo, enquanto todo/toda caracteriza o sujeito.